# React Jest: Is it possible to configure a truststore?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, jsdom

i’m new to web-frontend-development and started a project with react. I’m currently at writing services (and tests for them using jest) for connecting to a rest api and websockets for backend communication and there i’m facing a problem:

The api and websocket are TLS (HTTPs/wss) protected and the jest tests run against an backend that uses self-signed certificates, which leads to websocket connections and HTTPs-Calls being not performed because of the server certificate that is not trusted in the client/test-env.

So i think that i am going to need some possibility to add my server certificate to the test environment or somehow configure it to allow untrusted tls connections.

Is that possible? If yes: how would I do that? Or are there any other things I could do?

Edit: I used create-react-app to initialize the development environment.

Comment: Why do the tests need to run against a backend? Generally for testing environments you can simply mock the data so you don't have to worry about this. If you have some example tests feel free to share

Comment: In my opinion you are testing the react application and at no point you should perform side effects such as api calls or establishing websocket connection in those tests, because you don't want your frontend testing to be ko because the api is currently unavailable. You should really mock those things.

Comment: @nubinub + aug : thanks for your input - you may be right, but what I’m trying to do here is integration testing. Or is that unusual for frontends?